# Security issue: Storing Stripe Response Data

Tags: stripe-payments

I was wondering is there any issue storing any data that is returned from stripe into a backend database. I was thinking of the charge id once the charge has been made.

- This is an example from Stripe api on create a charge.

[Stripe : Create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge)

```html
Stripe\Charge JSON: {
  "id": "ch_18FZX8CBgCsd1mBnmBbSzh4M",
  "object": "charge",
  "amount": 2000,
  "amount_refunded": 0,
  "application_fee": null,
  "balance_transaction": "txn_18EXdtCBgCsd1mBn4RdsEaqI",
  "captured": true,
  "created": 1464311582,
```

I was thinking of storing the id

```
"id": "ch_18FZX8CBgCsd1mBnmBbSzh4M"
```

Is this safe? Or is there a better way of doing it? Can users be permitted to see this charge id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That information is really only valuable with your secret API key. And if an attacker gets your secret key, they can get all your past charges without knowing their ids anyway - the Stripe API has a `list` function to retrieve them all. The charge id alone can't be used for anything.